# Mysql varchar unique column varchar(255) vs. varchar(50)

Tags: php, mysql

I will always be entering things of 20 characters into a particular column in my table.

I need this column to be unique.

Will there be any speed difference in SELECT queries if I set this column to be a varchar(255) instead of varchar(20)?

(data entered will always be 20 characters)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if data entered will **always be** 20 characters than why not consider using **char(20)**. using varchar(20) will use 20 bytes for storing character and 1 byte for storing length. so if there are 1 million records, 1 million bytes will be wasted.

as far as speed is concerned between varchar(20) and varchar(255), then I dont think it might be very hard to pick one of them, both of them will be using 21 bytes, I dont see any significant performance benefit or loss of one over other.

Answer (score 3):

If it can only be 20, why would you want to specify 255?  If it is always 20, even char(20) would be better.

Comment: Future proofing (we might upgrade SLI codes next year).  Also, I am curios to see what the answer will be.

Comment: Don't future-proof!  Do you think column widths are carved in stone?  If you need to change in the future, change it *in* the future.  Might as well set it to varchar(5000) now, just in case.

Comment: Is there any reason I should not set it to varchar(5000) I thought the max was 255?

Comment: My point was, don't just set everything to MAX on the off-chance that one day you might need it.  Especially not when it is generally very easy to increase the size of a column, compared to reducing it.

Answer (score 2):

in select query you are not gain speed increasing by reducing length of varchar but you can increase speed of insertion a new record

Answer (score 2):

If you are pretty sure that all values will be `20 chars` and they will be of **fixed lenght**  then do go with `char(20)` as you will gain space and a slight amount of speed.

```
Value       CHAR(4)  Storage Required   VARCHAR(4)  Storage Required
''          '    '           4 bytes            ''            1 byte
'ab'        'ab  '           4 bytes          'ab'           3 bytes
'abcd'      'abcd'           4 bytes        'abcd'           5 bytes
'abcdefgh'  'abcd'           4 bytes        'abcd'           5 bytes
```

The [above table is taken from MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/char.html) and I do advise you to read the comments on that thread (sample bellow)

Posted by Kirby Wirby on April 9 2007 8:33pm

- *Consider the case of an indicator field where the value is either 'Y' or 'N'. If defined as a CHAR, the field requires only one byte.
  However, if defined as a VARCHAR, the field requires two bytes.*

Answer (score 1):

Best thing is to allocate as much space as it needs, cause MySQL often allocates fixed-size chunks of memory to hold values internally.

This is bad for *sorting* or operations that use *in-memory temporary tables*. The same thing happens with *filesorts* that use *on-disk temporary tables*. The book **High Performance MySQL** gives more information about these issues. I advise to read it.