# Hibernate fails to map MySQL varchar(255)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

How do I define this column?  I have tried:

```
    //@Column(name="GLN_NM", nullable=false, length=255)
    //@Column(name="GLN_NM", nullable=false)
    //@Column(name="GLN_NM", nullable=false, columnDefinition="varchar(255)")
    //@Column(name="GLN_NM", nullable=false, type="text")
    //@Column(name="GLN_NM", nullable=false, columnDefinition="text")
    //@Column(name="GLN_NM", nullable=false, columnDefinition="TextType")
    @Column(name="GLN_NM", length=255)
    private String glnNm;
```

The issue I see is Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
 Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [GPC_NM] in table [gs1_gpc]; found [text (Types#LONGVARCHAR)], but expecting [longtext (Types#CLOB)]

The software stack
* MySQL 5.7.17 
* mysql-connector-java-5.1.41 
* sbt  0.13.15
* hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final
* hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final
* hibernate-entitymanager-5.2.10.Final
* hibernate-validator:5.2.4.Final
* hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar

I have read https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html and several articles:
[6207788](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207788/how-to-map-a-mysql-charn-column-to-an-instance-variable-using-a-jpa-hibernate#6207865),
[16641758](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641758/convert-string-to-clob-and-vice-versa-in-hibernate),
[40884306](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40884306/schema-validation-wrong-column-type-encountered-in-column-in-table-fou),
[28588311](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28588311/correct-jpa-annotation-for-postgresqls-text-type-without-hibernate-annotations),
[26774193](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774193/hibernateexception-wrong-column-typex-expected-y-on-sybase),
[3868096](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868096/jpa-how-do-i-persist-a-string-into-a-database-field-type-mysql-text),
[12398597](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12398597/mysql-varchar-255-and-above),
[8355669](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355669/mysql-varchar-unique-column-varchar255-vs-varchar50),
[12672764](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672764/mysql-varchar-255-limitation-anomaly),
[10043556](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10043556/mysql-why-varchar254-and-not-varchar255),
[1262174](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262174/mysql-why-use-varchar20-instead-of-varchar255).

Open Product Data (http://www.product-open-data.com/download/) defines the table as:

```
"Field"         "Type"      "Null"  "Key"   "Default"
"GCP_CD"    "varchar(13)"   "NO"    "PRI"   \N
"GLN_CD"    "varchar(13)"   "NO"    ""  \N
"GLN_NM"    "varchar(255)"  "NO"    ""  \N
"GLN_ADDR_02"   "varchar(38)"   "NO"    ""  \N
"GLN_ADDR_03"   "varchar(38)"   "NO"    ""  \N
"GLN_ADDR_04"   "varchar(38)"   "NO"    ""  \N
"GLN_ADDR_POSTALCODE" "varchar(38)" "NO" "" \N
"GLN_ADDR_CITY" "varchar(38)"   "NO"    ""  \N
"GLN_COUNTRY_ISO_CD" "varchar(38)" "NO" ""  \N
"CONTACT_NAME"  "varchar(38)"   "NO"    ""  \N
"CONTACT_TEL"   "varchar(255)"  "NO"    ""  \N
"CONTACT_HOTLINE" "varchar(255)" "YES"  ""  \N
"CONTACT_FAX"   "varchar(255)"  "NO"    ""  \N
"CONTACT_MAIL"  "varchar(255)"  "NO"    ""  \N
"CONTACT_WEB"   "varchar(255)"  "NO"    ""  \N
"GLN_LAST_CHANGE" "varchar(10)" "NO"    ""  \N
"GLN_PROVIDER"  "varchar(13)"   "NO"    ""  \N
"SEARCH_GTIN_CD" "varchar(13)"  "NO"    ""  \N
"GEPIR_GCP_CD"  "varchar(13)"   "NO"    ""  \N
"ADD_PARTY_ID"  "varchar(13)"   "NO"    ""  \N
"RETURN_CODE"   "varchar(3)"    "NO"    ""  \N
"SOURCE"    "varchar(100)"  "NO"    ""  \N
"SYNC_DT"   "date"  "YES"   ""  \N
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure, that this column is giving you trouble? Your Stacktrace suggests that Hibernate is complaining about GPP_NM, not GLN_NM

Comment: Winner!  I hate when I misread things like that!  Thank you!  I will focus on [GPC_NM] and move on..

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to specify columnDefinition like columnDefinition="text" in your pojo.

Instead just put in your pojo:
@Column(name="GLN_NM")
 private String glnNm;

In your mysql define that column as:
varchar(256) or LongText or MediumText based on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for trying  
 @Column(name="GLN_NM")
 private String glnNm;

Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [GPC_NM] in table [gs1_gpc]; found [text (Types#LONGVARCHAR)], but expecting [longtext (Types#CLOB)]

Comment: Can you please show what you defined as data type for the column in mysql?

Comment: Hi Tanmay, I have added it to the original post.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments above, the `GLN_NM` column is working just fine. The troublemaker is the `GPC_NM` column (not included in OPs original code)